# Is it possible to pass multiple lines of HTML as a string argument to a HTML helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

My use case is I have a html template I wish to compile server side but define inside of a RAZOR view.

Rendering out this template using RAZOR syntax is not possible because the value are only ever client side. Like jQuery templates and the like.

Ideally, it would be passed in as such from tje view:

```
@Html.Template(<this somehow indicates it's the start of my string>
    <div>Hello {{= NameOfHomePlanet }}</div>
    <div>And welcome to a second line!</div>
</this somehow indicates it's the end of my string>);
```

Now in the helper:

```
public static Template(this Html html, string template) 
{
    // tmplate == "    <div>Hello {{= NameOfHomePlanet }}</div>\n"
    // + "<div>And welcome to a second line!</div>";
}
```

That would result in that HTML between the outermost fictional tags being passed in as the first argument of the Html helper named Template.

In playing with  I was unable to get the syntax to work out. Is this possible?

Comment: The HTML has a predefined structure? I would suggest that you make a different HtmlHelper for each use of you need. Let's say, one HtmlHelper for handling "PlanetWelcome", where you pass "NameOfHomePlanet" and any other info as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing this but you certainly could

```
@{
  string someHtml = "<div>" + model.NameOfHomePlanet + "</div>";
}

@Html.CustomHelperTemplate(someHtml)
```

Beyond that it's hard to tell because your question is very vague.

Comment: I'll update the main topic to be more specific. I can see how it is vague.